# How to get data from php as JSON and display on label swift

Tags: json, swift

Here is my code

```
func requestPost () {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://oakkohost.000webhostapp.com/test.php") as! URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "numQue"

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("post: \(responseString)")

                }
    task.resume()
}}
```

The result is

> [{"id":"147","date_timestamp":"2017-06-26 16:42:16"}]

The problem is I want to use this result which the id to my label in Swift Code How can I use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use `JSONSerialization` to get your `JSON` object from `data`. Also in Swift 3 use `URLRequest` and `URL` instead of `NSMutableURLRequest` and `NSURL`.

```
func requestPost () {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://oakkohost.000webhostapp.com/test.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "numQue"

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]], 
           let obj = array.first {

             let id = obj["id"] as? String
             //Set id to label on main thread
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.yourIdLabel.text = id
             }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json: [Any]?
do {
    // Get json from data
    json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [Any]
} catch {
    print(error)
}
// Get item from json object
guard let item = json?.first as? [String: Any],
    let id = item["id"] as? [String: Any] else {
        return
}
// Assign the `id` to your label
yourLabel.text = id
```

Comment: it got the error "jsonObject produces Any not the expected contextual result type [Any]" help meee

Comment: I've edited my answer. Basically just cast `.jsonObject` to `[Any]`. The answer from @NiravD should also work.