# How to get username and password variables from a MySql Database for an IOS app?

Tags: php, mysql, swift, database, authentication

I started IOS programming a few weeks ago and I'm trying to create a login page that pulls an username and password from a database that I've already created. I've set up the php file and linked it up to server and the info prints correctly. The problem I'm trying to solve is how to pull the data from the actual app(the Xcode Swift file).

I have been looking on the internet for a few days and the only thing I can find is how to print the data and not how to store it into a variable to cross-check with the user's username and password.

My PHP File:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

    // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
// If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
// to hold the data
$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();

// Loop through each row in the result set
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}

// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Could someone guide me in the right direction to get the data from the server and store it into a variable in swift code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816487/how-to-get-data-from-php-as-json-and-display-on-label-swift

Comment: So, you want to know how to post data to your website via your App?  Do you know how a HTTP post works?  Do you know how a multipart form HTTP post works?